# Background-size: auto; vs. not setting a background size

Tags: html, css, image

My question is, When do you set it to auto, and when is it fine not to put a background-size at all?

In what circumstance would you use, or not use each?

```
background-size: auto;
```

Default value.

**vs.**

not setting a background size.

This is also Default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto` is the default value. There is no difference between "not setting a background size" and "setting it to auto".

A specific use case for `auto` is to override a style set by something else. Or to create a style "reset". Specifically, if one `css` rule declares the `background-size: cover`, you can use `auto` as part of a different declaration to reset it.

Refer to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for more details.

Comment: Center vs. center center: Why would one use one over the other, and do each serve a different purpose?

background-position: center;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position
vs.
background-position: center center;
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp